# Deactivate button on click for 10 minutes (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have button in my iOS app:

```
    _Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *shareIMG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];
    [_Button setBackgroundImage:shareIMG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_Button addSubview:titleLabel];

    UILabel * titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 3, shareIMG.size.width, shareIMG.size.height)];
    [titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [titleLabel setText:@"Button";
    [_Button addSubview:titleLabel];
    [titleLabel release];
    [_Button setFrame:CGRectMake(2 * self.sendPushButton.frame.origin.x + self.sendPushButton.frame.size.width , 380 - liteIndent1 - liteIndent2 + iphone5Fix, shareIMG.size.width, shareIMG.size.height)];
    [self addSubview:_Button];
```

Could you help me how to make this button inactive (button_non_active.png) and un-clickable for 10 minutes after click?

Comment: Even if the app is killed and restarted?

Comment: use NSTimer on click of button, make it disabled or make its userInteraction as false and set timer to 10 minutes and on NSTimer function make button enabled or userInteraction TRUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in the same class that will re-enable it:

```
-(void)enableButton:(UIButton *)button {
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.enabled = YES;
}
```

And the selector that will be fired when it is pressed (you seem to be missing this from your snippet.  Set it with `[_Button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`)

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    //do actual action here
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_non_active.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
    button.enabled = NO;
    [self performSelector: @selector(enableButton:) withObject: button afterDelay: 600.0];
}
```

Comment: Using your method button after bushing become non active but retaining  <button_active.png>  and after delay becomes active but with <button_non_active.png> image. What is wrong?

Comment: instead of `UIControlStateHighlighted`, try `UIControlStateNormal`.

Comment: I have tried that, but image did not became <button_non_active.png>, it makes only a little bit carder and thats all

Comment: fixes that with `button.alpha = 0.5;`

Answer (score 5):

```
// disable button
[_Button setEnabled:NO];

// run a selector after 10 minutes
[_Button performSelector:@selector(onEnableButton:) withObject:_Button afterDelay:(10.0 * 60.0)]


- (void) onEnableButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
 [sender setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Crashes and the button is not active from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Use   `

```
 btn.enabled=NO;`

  NSTimer  *   notificationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10*60.0 target:self selector:@selector(enable) userInfo:nil repeats:No];

    -(void)enable
    {
    btn.enabled=YES;
    }
```

Modify it just a guidance . Set repeat yes or No according to needs

Answer (score 0):

On click of button you have to call a function.

```
- (void)buttonClickedStartTimer
{
    _Button.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(stopTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)stopTimer
{
     _Button.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    [timer invalidate];
    [timer release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  _Button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_non_active.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [_Button addSubview:titleLabel];
   [_Button setEnabled:NO];

    int64_t delayInSeconds = 60.0 * 10;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
       [_Button setEnabled:YES];
    });
```